# Ggplot font size and plot size

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have any kind of plot as ggplot(). I want to plot it such that the width and height of the diagram are fixed (in cm) and that the font size is given in pt such as it is in Microsoft Word.

How do I do this? I tried `+theme (text=element_text(family="Arial", face="plain", size=12/.pt)` to make the font 12pt high but this makes it unreadably small.

Comment: If you look at the `size` argument in `?element_text()`, it states that text size is already in points. The extra division by `.pt` seems therefore unneccessary.

Comment: Thank you. This reduces my problems to just one.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `base_size` in `theme` for font and use `ggsave` to save the height and width or use `egg` `set_panel_size`
See this example with `iris` dataset:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw(base_size=12, base_family='Times New Roman') + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(title="Iris")


#to view the plot
gridExtra::grid.arrange(egg::set_panel_size(p=p, width=unit(5, "cm"), height=unit(8, "cm")))

#to save the plot
ggsave("figure1.png", dpi=300, dev='png', height=8, width=5, units="cm")
```